# How do I read this Object

Tags: c#

I want to read the alert message from the object

```
{
    alert = "1\n2\n3";
    sound = default;
}
```

I have tried serializing it to JSON with newtonsoft and I've also tried converting it to a class. but both failed due to the formatting.

Comment: That object's representation is  not valid JSON, so a JSON deserializer will not be able to handle it. You may have to write your own mini-parser.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for ideas how to read it.

Comment: What is "aps"? What is "payload"? What is "args"? Could it have been valid JSON before your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid JSON, so the best thing you can do is try to parse it yourself.

You can use a full-fledged parser/lexer for it, like ANTLR. You might get enough with some C# or regex, depending on other outputs to expect.

This regex might be a start:

```
alert = \"(.*?)\";.* sound = (.*?);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried serializing it to JSON

But that's not JSON.

So you could try with some regex to extract the desired value:

```
var match = Regex.Match(payloadStr, @"alert\s=\s\""(.+)\""");
if (match.Success)
{
    string alertText = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

As far as how reliable this regex is would very much depend on this custom format that is being used and what possible values it can get.